# Named Window vs Implicit Partition

Tags: mysql, window-functions

These three queries seem to produce the same results:

```
SELECT val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS row_num
FROM numbers
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY val);

SELECT val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_num
FROM numbers
ORDER BY val;

SELECT val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val) AS row_num
FROM numbers;
```

- Are these queries effectively identical or is there *any difference at all*?
- Will `row_num` always related to the same row in every case?

Comment: *Are these queries effectively identical or is there any difference at all?* 2nd query is not equivalent to anothe ones, it may produce the output which differs from the output produced by another two queries. 1st and 3rd are completely the same. *Will row_num always related to the same row in every case?* For queries 1 and 3 this is TRUE, for query 2 this is FALSE.

Comment: @Akina - Thanks.  Can you demonstrate or explain in what situation query 2 will produce different output?

Comment: In the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) it says that when the `OVER` clause is empty it "*treats the entire set of query rows as a single partition.*"

Comment: SQL is declarative. For query 2 server may sort then calculate ROW_NUMBER, but may firstly calculate then sort. And you cannot predict this. Accordingly I cannot demonstrate this behavior which is non-deterministic.

Comment: *it says that when the OVER clause is empty it "treats the entire set of query rows as a single partition."* True. But RM tells nothing about this partition ordering, is it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would usually consider the `ORDER BY` clause to be part of the "*entire set of query rows*", but maybe that's wrong.

Comment: Also, let's assume we're looking at the results of query #2 and it's ordered by `val` as expected.  Wouldn't it be pretty strange if `row_num` was out of order?

Comment: *let's assume we're looking at the results of query #2 and it's ordered by val as expected. Wouldn't it be pretty strange if row_num was out of order?* This is absolutely common state. *I would usually consider the ORDER BY clause to be part of the "entire set of query rows"* This is true. But you tell only WHAT to do and cannot tell HOW to do this, in what order. So server is free to calculate ROW_NUMBER (in some current rows ordering) then resort the rows in another order according to ORDER BY which will produce unordered ROW_NUMBER values in the output rowset.

Comment: The next question is:  Which is faster?

Comment: @RickJames - `EXPLAIN` shows identical plans for all three on this basic schema. I'm not sure if that would change in a more complex situation but as far as I can tell, they are equal.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE numbers`.

Comment: @RickJames I think it's not relevant to the question but... ``CREATE TABLE `numbers` (`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `val` int NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB``

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue - It may be significant that there is _not_ `INDEX(val)`, which would probably change most of the `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: @RickJames - No, the presence of an index on `val` doesn't change either query results or plan in this case.